# CREATE_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT for child process

Tags: windows, debugging

I have a simple debugger which i wrote, and i'm running it on a process which creates a child process.
The CREATE_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT is called only for the main process and not the child process (i'm opening this process with CreateProcess and DEBUG_PROCESS flag).

how can it be that CREATE_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT isn't called when child process starts?

Comment: When you say "this process" do you mean the main process or the child process?

Comment: I'm opening with CreateProcess the main process, which it creates a child process on it's own. Since in debugging the main process, I should see the CREATE_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT twice (one for the main process, and one for the child process it creates). But I only see a single event

Comment: Do you know how the child process is being created?  Have you double-checked (using Process Explorer, for example) whether the process that you're debugging really is the child's parent?

Answer (score 1):

[This page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681423(v=vs.85).aspx) indicates that a `CREATE_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT` generates a callback with "a handle to the image file of the process being debugged, a handle to the process being debugged, and a handle to the initial thread of the process being debugged". It doesn't say anything about the child process. Whereas the page on `CREATE_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT` does mention child processes. The reason I point this out is that there might be some undocumented stuff you have to do to get this to work.

One suggestion is to see if Windbg properly handles the case you're having trouble with. If it does, then debug Windbg and set a breakpoint on `WaitForDebugEvent`. See if there is anything different in how Windbg calls `WaitForDebugEvent` vs your debugger.

Another issue that occurs to me is that your debugger does not have rights to the child process. Running the above mentioned test with Windbg should tell you if that's the case.